# Multisim component name - voltage level convertor

Tags: multisim

How do I find the circled components on Multisim?
This is a logic voltage level convertor circuit.
I'm unable to find it anywhere in Multisim search.

Could it be that in new versions they removed this component?
The circuit in the picture is from Multisim, but quite old.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The marked items are (probably) off-page connectors.  They do not represent a physical part, but are just notation that the named signal comes from, or goes to, elsewhere - frequently to/from another schematic page.

They will not be in the physical part libraries.  I haven't used Multisim, so don't know where to find them (I used Altium, and don't recall where to find them there either - too long retired...)

Answer (score 0):

Good health!
I have version 14.2 Using its example, I’ll show you where you can get these designations from.[image]